# Bundle ID for App submission iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an existing app already on the app store... I want to upload a new app to the app store but its asking for a bundle ID? Can I use the same one I used for the first app or is it a new bundle ID for every new app?

Thank you!

Comment: Commonly, bundle ids use the format "com.mycompany.app-name".  In your case, you'd have "com.mycompany.first-app" and "com.mycompany.second-app".  But all this is optional: you could very well decide to arbitrary use anything as your bundle id. Just remember that it must be entirely unique for each app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create a new bundle ID.  Please see Apple's documentation, "iTunes Connect Developer Guide"

[iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

Specifically, the Bundle ID needs to be unique for each app.  You will also need a new iTunes connect profile.  It is, unfortunately, a complicated process.

Comment: You do not need a new signing certificate. And you only need a new profile if you're using non-wildcard app IDs.