# ios bundle id questions to start first facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5, bundle

I've been trying to learn how to do my first facebook app.  The directions at developers.facebook.com/apps/407656052586647/summary?web_hosting=0 asks for my ios bundle id.

I've looked on this website, and [Bundle ID Suffix? What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436260/bundle-id-suffix-what-is-it), discusses it (assuming bundle id and bundle suffix id are the same), and it sounds like it's linked to the apple id.  I'm just developing the app and don't have an apple id yet, assuming it's tied to distributing the app to itunes.  Which comes first, the chicken or the egg?  I haven't even written the app so how could I have an id for itunes?  I saw this [Bundle ID for App submission iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200686/bundle-id-for-app-submission-ios), but I'm absolutely not ready to submit it to itunes.

I read somewhere on this site that I need to go to xcode ->resource->settings bundle to create a bundle for the project.  Would I put every file for the project in the bundle in the finder window?

Also, the hackbook example, referred to in http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/comment-page-1/#comment-293743, in step 3 (it's calling it demoApp, but the name I found is Hackbook, but it's working as an example so far anyway) refers to setting the kAppId.  Their link to create an app id doesn't work.  Would it be the same as what I'm doing at developers.facebook.com in the first paragraph of this question above?  Would this app id be what I get from a successful submision at developers.facebook.com/apps/407656052586647/summary?save=1 ?  I see they are listing an app id and app secret code there, but it's not working because I don't have an ios bundle id?  Would the bundle id be my bundle name (drag contents of xcode project in)?

Thanks for any help you can provide...
Mich

Comment: You need a developer account to create App ID's which are linked to provisioning profiles, which are imported to Xcode and compared to the bundle ID you set in your app. (com.myCompanyName.myAwesomeAppName)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to worry about submitting the app to iTunes yet.

In order to get your app working with Facebook, you'll need to access https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

From there, click "Create New App"

Simply specify App Name.  App Namespace is not needed at this point and is optional.

Click Continue and you're new Facebook app will have been created.  From there, you will be provided your App Id.  Use your Facebook App Id in this line of code:

```
[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"<APP ID GOES HERE>" andDelegate:self];
```

[image: facebook screenshot showing App ID]

---

Comment: I am not sure you can still do that. The new API requires bundleID

Answer (score 1):

Your links dont work, but I think that they refer to the bundle ID on developer.facebook.com where you will need to create an App ID and use it in your iOS app. Did you do that already? Thats definitely a prerequisite before you even deal with itunes.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a popular question so I thought I'd add some more info on what I decided to do.  After I created the app id at the facebook developers link, I wound up using ShareKit2.0 to get the newer version of ios to work.  The Hackbook/Demo example at the link above is in the older ios version so I couldn't get it to work with ios5.  It was helpful to use the Hackbook to figure out what I needed for permissions, but that's it.  I wound up following the SharKit2.0 directions (not at their website, go to the git version that the community is currently updating).  [Static Facebook sdk has no .m files in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388298/static-facebook-sdk-has-no-m-files-in-it)

The directions that are at the link were helpful to create and start my first facebook app including app id.  I never wound up doing anything with Bundle.