# Finding Bundle/Developer for used App Name

Tags: iphone, ios, bundle

I'm trying to upload an app to the app store and getting the following error (which is easy enough to understand):

`The App Name you have entered has already been used`

The app is not on the iTunes. Is there any way to figure out who owns the app or what bundle id it is associated with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200686/bundle-id-for-app-submission-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App names can be reserved for 180 days (6 months) as detailed here: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW20)

> After creating your app and it is in the state Prepare For Upload or 
>   Waiting For Upload, you have 180 days (6 months) from your creation
>   date  in iTunes Connect to deliver a binary to Apple.  If you do not
>   deliver a  binary before the 180-day deadline, your app is deleted
>   from iTunes  Connect.  As a result of this deletion, your app name can
>   be used by  another developer and you cannot reuse the app name, SKU
>   or bundle ID.   See “Deleting an App” to learn more about the
>   ramifications of App Delete.

This may be why the app is not in the store. There's no official way to find out who owns that name, or what the bundle ID is. That is all private to the developer's development account.

Answer (score 1):

It's means the app name is already registered by another developer. If that developer already releases the app then you can find the app by searching the app name in iTunes store.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same bundle id..you just have to put different name in the app store.

It is not possible to find out the bundle id associated with it..since it might be possible it has not released on the app store